# How to implement secure connection to CBPeripheral?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I want only trusted devices to connect to my peripheral. And I don't want anyone to be able to discover services and characteristics of my peripheral.
So before connecting to the peripheral I would like to show an alert with a pin code. Is it possible to do it and what is the easiest way?

I couldn't find the answer to this question and tried to implement encrypted characteristic by adding CBAttributePermissionsWriteEncryptionRequired to the permissions:

```
self.characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[JUUIDBuilder uuidWith:@"1706"]
                                                         properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
                                                              value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsWriteEncryptionRequired];
```

For some reason it didn't help because I'm able to write values from my second device all the time without any security checks. (Documentation for CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired says:

> ...the characteristic is configured to allow only trusted devices to read or subscribe to its value. When a connected, remote central tries to read or subscribe to this characteristic’s value, Core Bluetooth tries to pair your local peripheral with the central to create a secure connection.

which doesn't make sense to me. What is "trusted devices" here?

Can anyone help me? What is the best practice to allow connections only from trusted devices with pin code confirmation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent services and characteristics being discovered.  You can advertise a primary service and have secondary services that aren't advertised, but once a connection is made all services and characteristics will be revealed.

If you specify that an attribute requires encryption, then a pairing (technically bonding) process will be initiated when you first try to read/write the characteristic.  This process exchanges encryption keys and results in the devices 'trusting' each other.

If your peripheral and central are both iOS8 devices, then I have found that if both devices are configured with the same iCloud account then the trust is already established (presumably for functions such handoff) and you will never see the pairing dialog.  This caused me quite a bit of confusion when I was trying to test encrypted characteristics.

If you test using devices with different iCloud accounts then you should see the pairing dialog.

Even the pairing process will not "protect" your service/characteristic if the "attacker" has control of both devices as they can simply complete the pairing process.  Pairing/bonding does protect the data against eavesdropping as the transfer will be encrypted.

To actually protect the service you would need some form of challenge/response involving a characteristic before exposing data.

For example the central needs to read a value from characteristic "A" which is set at random by the peripheral.  The central then needs to calculate the correct response to that value and write it back to "A".  Only if this value is correct does the peripheral set values on the remaining characteristics (or accept inputs on the other characteristics from the central).

This solution is only secure as long as your challenge/response mechanism isn't compromised but will probably defeat non-determined attackers.

Comment: thank you. You're right, the issues was that these devices shared one iCloud account.

Comment: btw, now central shows pin code and peripheral requires this code. Is it possible to make central to enter pin code?