# Unable to show the pairing dialog using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth

Hello I am using the Apple Sample BLTE app to show the pairing dialog.(iPhone to iPhone)

This is my code for creating the characteristic

```
self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]
                                                                  properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyRead| CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired
                                                                       value:nil
                                                                 permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];
```

Above code was taken from one of Apple's articles [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html)

This is my code for when I am notifying and trying to read from the characteristic

```
if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]]) {
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];

        [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
```

My problem is that when I try this code I dont get a pairing dialog, instead I get this error in `didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`

```
2017-04-24 17:24:58.636 BTLE Transfer[1351:457263] Error discovering characteristics: Authentication is insufficient.
```

Which basically means that I need a pairing to read, but the framework doesn't show the pairing dialog.

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

**EDIT:**
I updated my characteristic as below:

```
self.transferCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]
                                                                  properties: CBCharacteristicPropertyRead| CBCharacteristicPropertyNotifyEncryptionRequired
                                                                       value:nil
                                                                 permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired];
```

Comment: Add `CBAttributePermissionsReadEncryptionRequired` to the permissions?

Comment: I am getting this error now `Error discovering characteristics: Reading is not permitted.` after changing the permissions. No pairing dialog still. Also it doesn't seem to hit  my `didReceiveReadRequest` delegate now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem why the pairing dialog was not showing up was because I had the same iCloud account on both the iphone. The pairing dialog showed up when I removed the account from one device.

This answer helped me to figure it out [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30905332/6925308)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Bluetooth Low Energy (without encryption), there is no pairing dialog...
You have to implement a pairing by yourself.

You can subscribe to characteristics / get notifications and read from or write to, that's all. You have to implement the corresponding methods from CBPeripheralManagerDelegate. Set the delegate of your peripheralManager and the methods will be called.

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate?language=objc

Comment: I am using encryption as mentioned in the code above. According to Apple docs the core Bluetooth framework should handle the pairing when read/wrote fails but it's not happening in my case. This is the problem